# How to override Glassfish timeout configuration programmatically for a method or bean?

Tags: java, nginx, glassfish, java-ee-7

I have a bean dedicated to export a CSV and due to the big amount of data it takes around 15 minutes o more and I get a timeout.

In order to solve this I thought about adding some kind of configuration only for this bean, as I mustn't increase Glassfish timeouts. So in my local machine I changed Glassfish timeout configurations to make some tests and reduce those 15 minutes (Request Timeout from Network Listeners and IDLE timeout from Thread Pools) and, by adding just a @Transactional annotation it worked, but when I used a preproduction machine it didn't.

Both are Glassfish 4.1.1, but in preproduction I also use Nginx. But trying through the 8181 port (HTTPS, which my Nginx doesn't control) it didn't work neither.

So I've been trying different solutions:

- @Transactional (cause transactions timeout is 0 in Glassfish)
- Use a EJB
- @StatefulTimeout
- @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER) and @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)

None of this worked in preproduction. Can someone guide me a bit?

**Edit:**
This is my configuration of Nginx.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    client_max_body_size 900M;
    server_name *my config*;
    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

The thing is even though setting timeouts in Glassfish and reducing it to 1 minute, in preproducction I can't avoid that timeout and the connection closes after that minute.

Comment: Just to get the full picture: Is nginx configured as reverse-proxy in front of Glassfish? What's the request timeout configuration of nginx?

Comment: I added my Nginx configuration. Proxy_[read-send-connect]-timeout have default values. The thing is even though setting timeouts in Glassfish and reducing it to 1 minute, in preproducction I can't avoid that timeout and the connection closes after that minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long transactions are in general not a good idea for an online application. That taken into consideration it makes probably sense to limit connection timeout to 1 minute.

What you can do is to perform the actual CSV export asynchronously in background. By annotating a business method of a stateless session bean with `@Async`, the method will be executed in a separate thread, while the original request is completed immediately. Transaction timeout of `@Async` annotated method need to be increased, of course, but that you might have already done. Since the initial request ends immediately, timeout isn't an issue anymore. And export is performed in background on the server, without a connection to the client.

Note: Business methods annotated with `@Async` are by default started in a new transaction.

The remaining problem is to properly report back the result of CSV export to the user, if that is needed. After the initial request, the user can only be told, that the CSV export job has been triggered, but not whether it finished successfully. One possible solution is, that the long-running export method returns a `FutureResult<ExportJobResult>`, that is registered in a `@Singleton` keyed by a job-id. The generated job-id (e.g. an UUID) is returned to the client with the initial response. The client can then poll, let's say every 10 seconds, for status of the `Future` object (checking for `isDone()`). A more elaborated solution would be a complete job management framework, that persists job status.

Comment: I tried with `@Asynchronous` and `@Singleton/@Stateless` and `@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)` + `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)` +  `@Resource UserTransaction`  in order to use the `setTransactionTimeout`method of that user transaction. I've been trying different combinations unsuccessfully. When you said _"Transaction timeout of @Async annotated method need to be increased, of course, but that you might have already done"_ you meant modifing Glassflish setup? Or local changes only for thar method, which is what I need?

Comment: Is the error message same as [link](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21495)?

Comment: I finally changed the method. First, I generate a CSV in a @Asycnchronous method and I made other view to download the files generated. In that new method I get the same error as in the link you posted. Actually, the person who reported the bug is doing the same as me _The method triggering this rollback imports a fair amount of data and regularly flushes the persistence context. Yet, once completed after several minutes, the warning and rollback occur._ Thanks a lot for your help!